# Mixing Templated Argument Types

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, std, generic-programming

How are mixed data types handled in C++ template/generic programming and overloaded operators?

For example, imagine that we are creating a two-dimensional coordinate class with x and y arguments, and we want to add them:

```
template <class T>
class Cartesian {
public:
    Cartesian();
    Cartesian(T _x, T _y);
    Cartesian<T> operator + (const Cartesian<T> & rhs);
    // setters, getters
private:
    T x, y;
};
```

`+` operator overload to add two coordinates:

```
template <class T>
Cartesian<T> Cartesian<T>::operator + (const Cartesian<T> & rhs) {return Cartesian(x+rhs.x,y+rhs.y);}
```

Now, we instantiate four points: two with `int` coefficients; the other two with `float`:

```
int main() {
    Cartesian<int> i1(1,2), i2(3,4);
    Cartesian<float> f1(5.7, 2.3), f2(9.8, 7.43);
```

Adding two ints is no problem, as is adding two floats. But what if we want to add an int to a float?? Even in a 4th grade classroom this would not present an issue, but here...

```
(i1 + i2); // ok
(f1 + f2); // ok
(i1 + f2); // uh oh!!!
```

Is there an easy way to handle this situation? Thx! :)

Comment: There are different ways of doing this.But first you have to decide: what should the return type be?

Comment: You need to add an operator overload for `Cartesian<int>() + Cartesian<float>`. They are two distinct types.

Comment: Joel that's ridiculous. What if I want to add a double to a float? int to a double? And then extend this to subtraction, multiplication, etc.. I'll have hundreds of overloads to define!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a free `operator+` overload.

```
template <class T, class U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value && 
  std::is_arithmetic<U>::value, Cartesian<std::common_type_t<T, U>>>::type 
operator + (Cartesian<T> const & lhs, Cartesian<U> const & rhs) 
{
    return Cartesian<std::common_type_t<T, U>>(lhs.x+rhs.x,lhs.y+rhs.y);
}
```

Replace `std::common_type_t<T, U>` by `typename std::common_type<T,U>::type` if pre C++14.

Now you can perform said operations:

```
Cartesian<int> i1(1, 2), i2(3, 4);
Cartesian<float> f1(5.7, 2.3), f2(9.8, 7.43);
auto a = i1 + i2; // a === Cartesian<int>
auto b = f1 + f2; // b === Cartesian<float>
auto c = i1 + f2; // c === Cartesian<float>
```

Comment: With C++11 a function template can have defaulted template parameters so it's more clear to put the enable_if in the `template<...>`, instead of mangling the return type.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Why do you think so?

Answer (score 3):

I would just define a factory function providing argument type deduction,

```
template< class T >
auto cartesian( T const x, T const y )
    -> Cartesian<T>
{ return {x, y}; }
```

Then a free-standing `operator+` like

```
template< class U, class V >
auto operator+( Cartesian<U> const& a, Cartesian<V> const& b )
{ return cartesian( a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y ); }
```

Huh, that was easy.

Comment: Cleaner and more generic (if C++14 is available). Take your +1 - even though I don't like that trailing return type here.